# How do I create a POST request in django rest framework with this model structure

Tags: python, json, django, post, django-rest-framework

I am new in django and django rest framework ,  I am trying to send an object with POST request, but i don´t know why it's failing, these are my models:

```
class Region(models.Model):
id_region = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name_region = models.CharField(max_length=255) 

def __str__(self):
    return self.name_region


class DataTicker(models.Model):
id_data_ticker = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ytd = models.FloatField()
expense_ratio = models.FloatField()
price_earnings_ratio = models.FloatField()
price_book_ratio = models.FloatField()
aum_ticker = models.FloatField()
price = models.FloatField()
nav = models.FloatField()
bid_ask = models.FloatField()
premiun_discount = models.FloatField()
date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
region_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(Region,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
geography_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(Geography,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id_data_ticker)


class Ticker(models.Model):
id_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ticker_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
index_tracked = models.CharField(max_length=255)
fund = models.CharField(max_length=255)
focus = models.CharField(max_length=255)
inception_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
asset_id_fk = models.ForeignKey(AssetClass,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data_tickers = models.ManyToManyField(DataTicker)

def __str__(self):
    return self.ticker_id
```

And this are my serializers

```
class RegionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Region
    fields = ('id_region','name_region','geography_id_fk')

class DataTickerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = DataTicker
    fields = ('id_data_ticker','ytd','expense_ratio','price_earnings_ratio',
    'price_book_ratio','aum_ticker','price','nav','bid_ask','premiun_discount','date','region_id_fk','geography_id_fk')

region_id_fk =  serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_region_id_fk')
geography_id_fk =  serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_geography_id_fk')

def get_region_id_fk(self,obj):
    return obj.region_id_fk.name_region

def get_geography_id_fk(self,obj):
    return obj.geography_id_fk.name_geography

class TickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
#data_tickers = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DataTicker.objects.all(), many=True)
data_tickers = DataTickerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Ticker
    fields = ('id_number','ticker_id','index_tracked','fund',
    'focus','inception_date',
    'asset_id_fk','data_tickers')

asset_id_fk =  serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_asset_id_fk') 

def get_asset_id_fk(self,obj):
    return obj.asset_id_fk.name_asset
```

my views:

```
class RegionSViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Region.objects.all().order_by('id_region')
serializer_class = RegionSerializer


class TickerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Ticker.objects.all().order_by('id_number')
serializer_class = TickerSerializer

class DataTicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = DataTicker.objects.all().order_by('id_data_ticker')
serializer_class = DataTickerSerializer
```

And this is the object that i am trying to send:

var obj = {
                "ticker_id": "TEST",
                "index_tracked": "testing",
                "fund": "testing",
                "focus": "Testing",
                "inception_date": "2019-11-19T19:28:16Z",
                "asset_id_fk": 6,
                "data_tickers": [{
                    "id_data_ticker": 1,
                    "ytd": 0.126504,
                    "expense_ratio": 25.0,
                    "price_earnings_ratio": 20.257181,
                    "price_book_ratio": 2.345986,
                    "aum_ticker": 25290400.0,
                    "price": 10000.0,
                    "nav": 11000.0,
                    "bid_ask": 15000.0,
                    "premiun_discount": 2000.0,
                    "date": "2019-11-01T19:23:03Z",
                    "region_id_fk": "Europe",
                    "geography_id_fk": "Developed Europe"
                }]
            }

What i am doing wrong?
thanks!

Comment: You have to had apiview like this : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Comment: show error logsss

Comment: Please provide the traceback  last line info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your views you have to add a method call post 
See the example https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

````
class TickerList(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = TickerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)```
````